# SQL Update Syntax for Running Total

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create running total with 'Add', 'Cancel', 'Update'

Doc #  Amount
1      2,000
2      3,000

Running Total 5,000

Doc #  Amount
1      2,500 (updated)
2      3,000

Running Total 5,500

Comment: show the error message  ..and remove the improper database tag ..

Comment: What is all that code for? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: *Storing* a running total just gives you an opportunity for that stored value to be out of sync with your transactional data. Far better to compute it on demand, unless or until performance measures indicate that this isn't fast enough.

Comment: Remove the SAP tag, it is irrelevant

Comment: Add, cancel, update:  Are those buttons on a form of some sort? Please try to write the question so it can be answered. Right now the question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTPUT` feature of SQL.

`UPDATE table
SET column = value
OUTPUT **`